# Mist reloading chain structure from scratch

Tags: mist, synchronization, testnets

How come every time I close and open ethereumwallet it starts downloading the chain structure from scratch?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using parity. It seems to be more compatible and works quite nice.

https://parity.io/

Or are there any reasons why Ethereum Wallet is a must have?

Comment: For the question you ask at the end, it would be better to create a new question. (Though it's possible/probable it's already been answered previously.)